# Jquery Preview image before upload

Tags: jquery, html

i need to preview image before upload i tried following code but it's not doing anything.

```
<form name=”user_profile” id=”user_profile” action=”” method=”POST” enctype=”multipart/form-data” >

    <div class=”profile”>
       <img class=”list_prev” id=”user_old” src=”add path her for preview image from folder”>

    <input type=”file” id=”user_image” class=”image ” name=”user_image” value=”” onchange=”preview_profile_image(this)” />

    </div>

</form>
```

> This is my script..

```
 <script type=”text/javascript”>

    function preview_profile_image(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var filerdr = new FileReader();

            filerdr.onload = function(e) {
                jQuery(‘.list_prev’).attr(‘id’, e.target.result);
            }

            filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    </script>
```

> anyone please help me what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `src` instead of `id` at line `jQuery(‘.list_prev’).attr(‘src’, e.target.result);`

Answer (score 1):

change this line;

```
  jQuery(‘.list_prev’).attr(‘src’, e.target.result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `src` not `id`

And `readAsDataURL` should be after on-load.

```
filerdr.onload = function(e) {
    jQuery('.list_prev').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

```js
function preview_profile_image(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var filerdr = new FileReader();
      filerdr.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        jQuery('.list_prev').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);  
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="user_profile" id="user_profile" action=”” method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <div class="profile">
       <img class="list_prev" id="user_old" src="add path her for preview image from folder">

    <input type="file" id="user_image" class="image" name="user_image" value="" onchange="preview_profile_image(this)" />

    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor change just put `src` not `id`

here is code

```
 function preview_profile_image(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var filerdr = new FileReader();
    filerdr.onload = function(e) {
    jQuery(‘.list_prev’).attr(‘src’, e.target.result);
    }
    filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to preview an image before it's uploaded

your .js file

```
  $("#upload_img").change(function() {
 console.log(this);
 readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('#preview_img').attr('src', e.target.result);
   }

     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
 }
}
```

HTML File

```
     <input type="file" name="image" id="upload_img" class="form-control">
   <h5>preview</h5>
   <img src="#" id="preview_img" class="img-fluid" style="border-radius: 10px;">
```

Hope it helped you

You can also read the full article from here [preview image before upload](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2020/09/preview-image-before-upload-jquery.html)